# Why my WCF client encrypts the request when I change from WS-Security 1.0 to 1.1?

Tags: wcf, encryption, wcf-security, wcf-client

I'm trying to consume a java web service from a WCF client with this specifications:

- The request must be signed (but NOT encrypted). I have my client's certificate installed on my computer.
- The response is signed (not encrypted) by the server. I have the server's certificate installed on my computer.
- Communication is over HTTPS (certificate installed on my computer).

  This is the configuration of the client:

**Endpoint:**

```
<endpoint address="https://..."
     binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SincronSoapCustom" behaviorConfiguration="webEndpointExtern" 
    contract="Proves.Service.SincronSoap" name="SincronSoap">    
    <identity>
      <dns value="Test app"/>
    </identity>
</endpoint>
```

**Custom binding:**

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="SincronSoapCustom" >
      <security  authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"  allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" requireSignatureConfirmation="false" requireDerivedKeys="false" includeTimestamp="true" securityHeaderLayout="LaxTimestampLast" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10">
      </security>         
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8"  ></textMessageEncoding>
      <httpsTransport transferMode="Buffered"  ></httpsTransport>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

**Behavior:**

```
<behavior name="webEndpointExtern">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="19cab2cd6bc982fb" storeLocation="CurrentUser"
          storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" />
        <serviceCertificate>
          <defaultCertificate findValue="311a360557c1056c5367435e7dad3866" storeLocation="CurrentUser"
            storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" />
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
</behavior>
```

To only sign the message (and avoid encryption) I set the protection level in the service contract:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0"),
     System.ServiceModel.ServiceContract([Namespace]:="http://xxxx/", ProtectionLevel:=Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign)>
    Public Interface SincronSoap

        <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://xxxxxx", ReplyAction:="*", ProtectionLevel:=Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign),
         System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults:=True)>
        Function procesa(ByVal request As Service.procesaRequest) As Service.procesaResponse

        <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://xxxxxx", ReplyAction:="*")>
        Function procesaAsync(ByVal request As PdibService.procesaRequest) As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Service.procesaResponse)
    End Interface
```

With this configuration, my requests are processed correctly by the server but my client throws an error when processing the response:

**Cannot read the token from the 'SignatureConfirmation' element with the 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd' namespace for BinarySecretSecurityToken, with a '' ValueType. If this element is expected to be valid, ensure that security is configured to consume tokens with the name, namespace and value type specified.**

Ok, my client uses WS-Security 1.0 and the SignatureConfirmation element is only allowed in WS-Security 1.1. The provider of the service confirms to me that the correct versión is 1.1.
So I change from:

WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10

to:

WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10

But when I make a request using this config, the remote server returns an error:

**WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed; nested exception is: 
    org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (WSSecurityEngine: No crypto propery file supplied for decryption)**

It seems that in this case my client is including some encryption in the request and the server doesn't expects it. This is the request:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <ActivityId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics" CorrelationId="868039bc-362d-4d3b-93fa-afb7ccdaf7e9">8160d724-54b3-4aa5-acbd-82d26abbf3b5</ActivityId>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="uuid-caa9c9fc-8225-403e-b844-fffa7e439ec6-1">
            <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
               <DigestMethod xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            </e:EncryptionMethod>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
               <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                  <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbprintSHA1" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">M0m/j9IjdvtsfXoboTzGX4jRw5I=</o:KeyIdentifier>
               </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
            <e:CipherData>
               <e:CipherValue>..removed..</e:CipherValue>
            </e:CipherData>
         </e:EncryptedKey>
         <o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <!--Removed-->
         </o:BinarySecurityToken>
         <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="_0">
            <SignedInfo>
               <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
               <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1" />
               <Reference URI="#_1">
                  <Transforms>
                     <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                  </Transforms>
                  <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                  <DigestValue>m6K+Htbhimq+ncV9cu48xtaHCXU=</DigestValue>
               </Reference>
               <Reference URI="#uuid-caa9c9fc-8225-403e-b844-fffa7e439ec6-2">
                  <Transforms>
                     <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                  </Transforms>
                  <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                  <DigestValue>DptGdl9nICPuR7ym4VB4DAsT05o=</DigestValue>
               </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>b7kn3APi45hTIGgnbhSvwInLmMP=</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
               <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd" k:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey">
                  <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" URI="#uuid-caa9c9fc-8225-403e-b844-fffa7e439ec6-1" />
               </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
         </Signature>
         <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
               <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
               <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
               <Reference URI="#_0">
                  <Transforms>
                     <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                  </Transforms>
                  <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                  <DigestValue>80Q2miLGWvPm9Tl8qN2CwPHwbIA=</DigestValue>
               </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>..removed..</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
               <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                  <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-20121b2c-b772-4bc9-83fe-f422d6a80a0b-1" />
               </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
         </Signature>
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-caa9c9fc-8225-403e-b844-fffa7e439ec6-2">
            <u:Created>2017-01-23T11:48:37.635Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2017-01-23T11:53:37.635Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" u:Id="_1">
.................. removed ............................
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

And this is the request when I use WS-Security 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <ActivityId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics" CorrelationId="8797dc6e-b03a-4681-ab6f-6d52c561a79a">3e959f6f-2b84-4aca-a024-b5b50f429730</ActivityId>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <!--Removed-->
         </o:BinarySecurityToken>
         <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
               <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
               <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
               <Reference URI="#_1">
                  <Transforms>
                     <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                  </Transforms>
                  <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                  <DigestValue>frO7LOsocv71gm5QWTGhfem0VQY=</DigestValue>
               </Reference>
               <Reference URI="#uuid-5768e670-1786-4c0c-b563-0306ac7fc3eb-1">
                  <Transforms>
                     <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                  </Transforms>
                  <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                  <DigestValue>/FLwiT1IYuqSWdrthZRebVeql0c=</DigestValue>
               </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>..removed..</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
               <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                  <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-2cf2ba54-442a-422c-a2e7-b6861431c23b-2" />
               </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
         </Signature>
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-5768e670-1786-4c0c-b563-0306ac7fc3eb-1">
            <u:Created>2017-01-23T11:36:11.128Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2017-01-23T11:41:11.128Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" u:Id="_1">
    ... removed ...
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

In this case no encryption is included in the request.
The question is, **why my client uses encryption when I change from WS-Security 1.0 to 1.1?**

How can I avoid this?

Thanks.